# How to customize angular material input / select underline to box

Tags: angular, angular7

How to change angular material input/select underline to box (bootstrap input)

```
    .mat-form-field {
        border-radius : 4px;  
    }
```

```
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
      <mat-select>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
          {{food.viewValue}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#form-field-appearance-variants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mat-form-field have 4 type of appearances closest to the one you want is ***outline*** so your code must be

```
   <mat-form-field  appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
      <mat-select>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
          {{food.viewValue}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```